# Log Analytics - Synapse Analytics Notebook Usage metrics

Tags: azure-synapse, kql, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics, azure-synapse-analytics

I am looking for usage metrics of synapse analytics notebook execution from Log Analytics.

Usage metrics like who performed the most notebook executions, execution time and other notebook run metrics.

Is there a built-in table which I can query using KQL to get these metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a workaround on your issue, I found that there is no default table for Synapse Analytics notebook execution metrics in Log Analytics.

As a workaround, you can follow below steps to retrieve the logs.

Add a `diagnostic settings` and configure a synapse workspace to send logs to workspace.

[image]

Now you can query custom logs with below sample query by exploring the `AzureSynapseAnalyticsWorkspaces` table for notebook execution events.

```bash
<AzureSynapseAnalyticsWorkspaces> 
| where OperationName == "<required operation>" 
| summarize count() by Caller 
| top 20 by count_
```

Now go to the `logs>> synapse workspace` logs and use KQL query to query the `AzureSynapseAnalyticsWorkspacesNotebookLogs`.